# OAuth Extension Loading in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

Hi I am really struggling with this one.

I am developing with Google Analytics and Google Adwords; and I am using two separate Oauth libraries in the API Helper Libraries that are written by Google. One is an extension (oauth.so) for Adwords and the other is just a PHP class for Analytics.

When I alter my php.ini file to load the extension, my Analytics OAuth breaks. I think it maybe a conflict of the class names? I have tried changing the name, but haven't had any luck. I had thought that I came up with a solution: Using the dl() function to dynamically load the oauth.so extension on just the Adwords related pages (they are separate scripts):

```
dl('oauth.so');
```

Which works great on the command line! But it doesn't work in the browser. I refuse to believe that nobody has come across this issue before. I know that loading the extension from php.ini works in the browser, it just disables the Analytics class. Any one with experience with this, I'd love to hear your input, if you have any suggestions please feel free!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AdWords API PHP client library has been updated to allow for different OAuth libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/source/detail?r=178

You could even write your own OAuthHandler class that utilized the existing OAuth library that the Analytics library uses.

Answer (score 1):

It's been `removed from some SAPI's`, either switch to `CGI` for the webserver (brr), or try to fix the problem with your Analytics PHP class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, there's 15 different OAuth related classes that I would need to rename inside the OAuth Analytics Helper Library, changing the names of all these and where they are instantiated would be a nightmare. I'm on the brink of just setting up a second server with a version of PHP that has the extension and then just setting up a REST interface to communicate between the two'

Comment: Just to clarify were you suggesting that I install a second version of PHP as a CGI installation?

Comment: Not necessarily a 2nd one, but PHP as a module cannot use `dl`, either run (fast)CGI on the same webserver, or PHP as you like on a different webserver with a different .ini